# How to disable disk watermark allocation in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data elastic search in my spring boot application, I am working on my own machine where more than 90% of my harddisk is occupied.

Elastic search does not insert any data because 90% of my harddisk is used and I only use 1 shard so for now I need to disable the allocation , of course in the production I will be using the allocation.

I already tried using allocation property in my application.properties

```
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled = false
```

I also tried increasing the high threshold to 99%

```
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high= .99
```

But both did not work , any idea how to disable it?

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the default value using this property

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high= .99
```